# Expected a valid redux store at invariant

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am having troubles creating a redux store for React website. How do I create the store here?

The error:

```
Uncaught Invariant Violation: (app/utils...) injectors: Expected a valid redux store
    at invariant
 ....
The above error occurred in the <HomePage> component:

    at HomePage (http://localhost:3000/static/js/src_containers_HomePage_index_js.chunk.js:232:5)
    at ConnectFunction (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:51172:68)
    at Suspense
    at Routes (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:54041:5)
    at IntlProvider (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:50235:43)
    at ParallaxProvider 
    .....
    at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:53974:15)
    at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:53449:5)
    at Provider (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:50883:20)
```

I am using react-router-dom v6.

src/index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { hydrateRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import rootReducer from './reducers'


const store = createStore(rootReducer, window.__PRELOADED_STATE__)

if (typeof window === 'object') {
    const container = document.getElementById("root");
    hydrateRoot(container,
        <React.StrictMode>
            <Provider store={store}>
                <BrowserRouter>
                        <App />
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use [redux-toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/) , it is easier to learn and use , and much less code is written with it ,the code provided is not enough.